# Como atualizar valor de atributo de qualquer elemento HTML de forma automática utilizando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Preciso manter o `title` de qualquer elemento na página atualizado. Sempre que um elemento possuir o valor de `title` sendo o caractere `?`, quero substituí-lo pelo valor contido dentro das tags do mesmo elemento.

O objetivo pode ser alcançado após a chamada da seguinte função, usando JQuery:

```js
function preencherTitle() {

    var elementos = $('[title="?"]');

    elementos.each(function() {
        this.title = this.textContent;
    });
}
```

Então, eu posso chamar quando a página estiver pronta, da seguinte forma:

```js
$(preencherTitle);
```

O problema é que isso não funciona após atualização do DOM por chamadas AJAX.
Caso eu crie um novo elemento, por uma chamada AJAX, que possua `[title="?"]`, a função não é chamada.

Então eu tentei:

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete(preencherTitle);
```

Isso também funciona, porém, apenas quando a chamada AJAX estiver marcada como `global`.

Preciso que a função seja acionada, também, quando a chamada AJAX não for `global`.

Acredito que eu possa estar trilhando o caminho errado para resolver esse problema, até porque não sou experiente em JavaScript.

Existe uma forma de alcançar o objetivo dessa função (mesmo sem, obrigatoriamente, utilizá-la) sempre que necessário, e de forma mais performática?

Comment: Como você está fazendo a chamada AJAX?

Comment: @LuizFelipe as chamadas AJAX são realizadas por componentes de outros frameworks, não tenho controle sobre isso. A princípio, não acho que posso considerar como são chamadas, pois são diversas possíveis chamadas a partir de um framework que eu "não controlo".

Comment: Não podes resolver isso no servidor?